# Libgdx: Actor as body

Tags: java, android, libgdx, box2d, actor

I'm beginner with libgdx and i looking for answer how to link actor and body(box2d) for a lot time, so please help me :(

I have following code:

```
/// CLASS ACTOR
public class MyActor extends Actor
    {
        Texture texture;
        float actorX = 0, actorY = 0;
        public boolean clicked = false;
        public String id;

        public MyActor(float x, float y, String id, String tekstura)
        {
            this.texture = new Texture(Gdx.files.internal(tekstura));
            this.id = id;
            actorX = x;
            actorY = y;

            setBounds(actorX, actorY, texture.getWidth(), texture.getHeight());
            addListener(new InputListener()
            {
                public boolean touchDown(InputEvent event, float x, float y,
                        int pointer, int button)
                {
                    MyActor co = ((MyActor) event.getTarget());
                    co.clicked = true;
                    System.out.println(co.id);
                    co.remove();
                    return true;
                }
            });
        }


        @Override
        public void draw(SpriteBatch batch, float alpha)
        {
            batch.draw(texture, actorX, actorY);
        }


    }

/*....................
.......................
........................
..........................*/
//CREATING SIMPLE OBJECT

        MyActor samolot1 = new MyActor(100, 300, "samolot1", "data/jet.png");
        samolot1.setTouchable(Touchable.enabled);
        stage.addActor(samolot1);


        // //////////////// WORLD /////////////////////////////////////////////

        // 1
        BodyDef bodydef_mojapostac = new BodyDef();
        bodydef_mojapostac.type = BodyType.DynamicBody;
        bodydef_mojapostac.position.set(400, 100);

        CircleShape shape_mojapostac = new CircleShape();
        shape_mojapostac.setRadius(30);

        FixtureDef fixturedef_mojapostac = new FixtureDef();
        fixturedef_mojapostac.density = 0.1f;
        fixturedef_mojapostac.friction = 0.8f;
        fixturedef_mojapostac.restitution = 0.7f;
        fixturedef_mojapostac.shape = shape_mojapostac;

        Body BodyMojaPostac = world.createBody(bodydef_mojapostac);
        BodyMojaPostac.createFixture(fixturedef_mojapostac);


        BodyMojaPostac.setUserData(samolot1);
```

and render()

```
......
batch.begin();
        world.getBodies(tmpBodies);
        for (Body body : tmpBodies)
            if (body.getUserData() != null)
            {
                System.out.println(body.getUserData());
                MyActor dupa = (MyActor) body.getUserData();
                batch.draw(dupa.texture, dupa.actorX, dupa.actorY);
            }
        batch.end();
.....
```

I can link body with sprite but i don't know how with actor :(

Comment: You might want to have a look at this: https://gist.github.com/nooone/8363982

Answer (score -1):

After having trouble with this combination as well I'd like to share my solution:

```
public class PhysicsActor extends Image {
private Body body;
private Fixture fixture;

public PhysicsActor(World world, BodyDef bodyDef, FixtureDef fixtureDef, TextureRegion textureRegion) {
    super(textureRegion);

    body = world.createBody(bodyDef);
    setFixture(getBody().createFixture(fixtureDef));
}

@Override
public void draw(Batch batch, float parentAlpha) {
    super.draw(batch, parentAlpha);
}

public Body getBody() {
    return body;
}

public Fixture getFixture() {
    return fixture;
}
```

I use it like this:

```
bodyDef = new BodyDef();
bodyDef.type = BodyType.DynamicBody;
bodyDef.position.set(Toolkit.Screen2World(x), Toolkit.Screen2World(y));

pShape = new PolygonShape();
pShape.setAsBox(Toolkit.Screen2World(width/2), Toolkit.Screen2World(height/2)); //In Toolkit I have my methods to scale the world

fixtureDef = new FixtureDef();
fixtureDef.shape = pShape;
//Set some more attributes i.e. density

//Add the PhysicsActor
PhysicsActor leftBar = new PhysicsActor(world, bodyDef, fixtureDef, new TextureRegion(Resources.barLeftTexture, 0, 0, width, height));
leftUpperBar.setSize(width, height);
this.addActor(leftUpperBar);
```

You only must set your width and height manually (in my case I use the resolution of my Texture).

Resources.barLeftTexture:

```
public static Texture barLeftTexture;

barLeftTexture = new Texture(Gdx.files.internal("data/barLeft.png"));
```

I noticed that your question may be outdated for you (the OP) but maybe it helps somebody stumbling across this question.

Comment: Nowhere in your solution do you show or explain how you migrate your body position to that of the GameActor. In addition there is no need for  a getBody call in the PhysicsActor construtor. You have the body there.